# Email tracking without embed image in email system

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am developing an application using Rails, there I need to track whether or not recipient read the sent mail. Basically I did this using embed image in email(html).

But due to image blocking in gmail I can't able to track it, in yahoo there I can see a link "show image" when user **clicks on that link** then I can track the details, but It shouldn't be like this, **without clicking on that link we need to track**.

**So I need a functionality similar to this, without using embed image, just when user reads the email I need to get notified.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** do this , because popular email services like gmail and yahoo blocking this type of tracking scripts.

Actually there are services ReadNotify.com , spypig.com , getnotify.com .. but now all these are not working as you expected . It is because of updations in security of email services.

All popular email services are blocking **malicious scripts** to protect their **users  privacy**.

refer following liks

https://wordtothewise.com/2013/12/gmail-deploys-image-proxy-servers/

Comment: Or there is any alternative for email_tracking, I could able to do this by using other ways with embed-image.

Comment: I think you can't do this anymore, as google like tech giants  are increasing security related user's privacy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bullet proof way for this. If you have html email you can also insert Javascript that is loading an external reference but most modern mail user agents block external references by default.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a service like Mailgun.com - they offer a ton of great tracking and reporting features that seem to work all major mail clients and gmail etc.

Re: https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#tracking-messages